# Plot a function of time

Tags: julia

I want to plot this function `r1(ω,t)` for a certain value of ω, parameterized by t (time) (in the x-y plane)

```
function r1(ω,t)
    return [cos(ω*t),sin(ω*t)]
end
```

I really don't know how to and I'm still learning how to search for Julia things online, I really suck at it at the moment.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Plots, we can directly broadcast the values

```
plot(cos.(ω*t), sin.(ω*t))
```

Also, you could directly implement the function similarly

```
f(ω,t) = [cos.(ω*t) s.(ω*t)]
plot(f(ω,t)[:,1], f(ω,t)[:,2]) #plugin values of ω, t
```